# How to set a limit on the time elapsed at a gams run

Tags: gams-math

We use resLim to set a limit on Elapsed time in solve statements, is there any way to set a time limit on overall time that a gams code runs, which is contains several solve statements in loops. i thought maybe a if like this will do but it doesn't help.

```
tii=TimeElapsed;
if(tii>10000, stop loops;)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [etLim](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_GamsCall.html#GAMSAOetlim) to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you, that's what i want, but still can't use it. i have tried 1) set etLim 100; 2) option  etLim=100; 3) trying command bar. also gams documentation is not clear about this option. can you please how to use it exactly?

Comment: I've used "gams myfile.gams etlim 400", "gams myfile.gams etlim 400" stille no luck

Comment: In the documentation it says "Available: Command line", so what you tried should actually work. Is your GAMS version up to date (version 32.1.0)? What does "no luck" mean? Any particular message in the log and/or lst file?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your respond, I use GAMS 24.1.2, in this version documentation exactly etLim option exist. by "no luck"  i mean the time limit I've set on etLim is not acting, and gams runs beyond this time limit. in the log file there is no sign of  etLim option.

Comment: In old versions, etLim did not influence the reslim for a particular solve, so if etLim gets exceeded while a solver is running, the solver will not be interrupted, but the execution stopped afterwards. This was changed with GAMS 32. This is from the release notes (https://www.gams.com/32/docs/RN_32.html#g3210_GAMS): "Extended the impact of command line parameter etLim, so that it reduces resLim for models solved automatically if that is greater than etLim - timeElapsed."

Comment: you're exactly right, that's the problem. Thank you for your time and help.